# $\bigcap_{j=1}^n m_j\subseteq m_{n+1}\implies \exists j~~ m_j=m_{n+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have distinct maximal ideals $m_1,m_2,\ldots\in \operatorname{Spec}_{\text{max}}(R)$, for an Artinian ring $R$.

I can't seem to figure out why we should now have
$$\bigcap_{j=1}^n m_j\subseteq m_{n+1}\implies  m_j=m_{n+1},\text{ for some $j\leq  n$}$$

Comment: $m_1\cdots m_n\subset\cap_{j=1}^nm_j$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on user26857's comment, note that for a prime ideal $P$ and ideals $I_1,\dots I_n$, we have $P\supset I_1\cdots I_n\implies P\supset I_j$ for some $j$. Apply this and then use maximality.